# Beta users prompted to download Public release App of Same Version

Tags: android

I have gone through two situations and finding hard to understand the issue/working behaviour. Wish some one could help please!!

- I am part of **Android Beta testing program** and installed the Beta build onto my device, say version 2. I was prompted to download App from Play Store which has version 1 (Version 2 is in Beta closed testing). I am quite confused with the process, higher version being prompted to download lower version. Should this be the expected behaviour and how does the flow work really?
- One of my colleague was part of Android Beta testing program and had the Beta build (Version 2) installed onto his device. Later App was released to Play Store (No build exist in Beta Closed testing). Build in App Store and Beta build in Device are Version 2, but the user is Prompted to download the App on Every launch. User has deleted Beta build and downloaded App from Play Store, but still the prompt appears to download. Why is this behaviour experienced and how to avoid this issue please?

Comment: the question is unclear, can you edit it ? im not getting the problem right, you say you install the bet with version 2 but then when install the public release it shows version 1 ?

Comment: have you accepted to become a tester of beta program?

Comment: @GastónSaillén Sorry to confuse you, I have installed the Beta Build Version 2 on my device, but Version 2 App is prompting me to download Version 1 from Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue sorted, it was to do with App itself, We have Force upgrade service in our App and was mistakenly enabled for latest version which prompted users to download on every launch.